# Unable to create new object

Tags: java, oop

I created these two files in java and they don't compile. This error comes up:

> cannot find symbol C02FootprintV1".

Why doesn't the program recognize the object? I am new to this.

How could I fix this problem?

```
public class CO2FootprintV1 {

    private double myGallonsUsed;
    private double myTonsCO2;
    private double myPoundsCO2;

    CO2FootprintV1(double gals) {
        myGallonsUsed = gals;
    }

    public void calcTonsCO2() {
        myTonsCO2 = myGallonsUsed * 0.878;
    }

    public double getTonsCO2() {
        return myTonsCO2;
    }

    public void convertTonsToPoundsCO2() {
        myPoundsCO2 = myTonsCO2 * 220462262;
    }

    public double getPoundsCO2() {
        return myPoundsCO2;
    }
}
```

```
public class CO2FootprintV1Tester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double gals;
        double tonsCO2, poundsCO2;

        gals = 1300;
        CO2FootprintV1 object = new C02FootprintV1(gals);

        object.calcTonsCO2();
        tonsCO2 = object.getTonsCO2();
        object.convertTonsToPoundsCO2();
        poundsCO2 = object.getPoundsCO2();
    }
}
```

Comment: `C02FootprintV1` isn't the same as `CO2FootprintV1`

Comment: lol Skeet beat me by ms:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change:

```
CO2FootprintV1 object = new C02FootprintV1(gals);
```

to:

```
CO2FootprintV1 object = new CO2FootprintV1(gals);
```

That's why it is important to have good naming practice.

Answer (score 2):

On the line

```
CO2FootprintV1 object = new C02FootprintV1(gals);
```

you have `C02` (see zero two) on the right hand side, you meant for it to be

```
CO2FootprintV1 object = new CO2FootprintV1(gals);
```

or `CO2` (see oh two). Also, you should consider that the error messages your tools give you might be correct.

Answer (score 1):

You put a "0" (cero) instead of an "O" (letter):

```
CO2FootprintV1 object = new C02FootprintV1(gals);
```

Try this:

```
  CO2FootprintV1 object = new CO2FootprintV1(gals);
```